# two fields validation with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to check uniqueness of a slug + category field.

I want to
   cross check both the fields with database..

both fields belongs in
   the same table..

category could be 1 or 2.

table name is pages..

my validation code is something like this

```
$catid = \Request::input('category');

$this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'slug' => "unique:pages|category,$catid",
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
```

i can't figure out what m i doing wrong?
any suggestions will be helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
'slug' => 'unique:pages,slug,NULL,id,category,' . $catid
```

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. :)